# How do I make the part of the line behind the "Who" disappear in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Easiest to explain this with code: http://jsfiddle.net/fjZfL/37/

I want it to be like

who ----------------

Where the line is totally "gone" behind who.

I know I could make the h3 have a white background to have it make it disappear, but my website has a background image, which if it was replicated again behind who it would look inconsistent.

You can absolutely change the markup, but hopefully not too much.

Comment: That is going to be a tough one, without changing the markup.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, go crazy with changing the markup if you see fit.

Comment: do you want it like this http://jsfiddle.net/fjZfL/41/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try adding a pseudo-element instead - http://jsfiddle.net/ZZbce/

```
h3:after {
    content: ''; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 1px; 
    background: black;
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle;   
}
```

Comment: Building on this: http://jsfiddle.net/fjZfL/43/ . While not all browsers support the `:after` pseudo-element, it's certainly the cleanest solution. +1

Comment: Yes, only IE8+ support, if you need older versions there are some JS polyfills you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..
http://jsfiddle.net/fjZfL/55/

THis will work in all browser